# How to disable a playing alarm during a call

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to disable a playing alarm when a call comes .
Only the call ringtone should be heard and not the alarm tone.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an activity, service or a anywhere you have a context object:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, true);
```

Just remember to take off the mute. Or, if your process is unneeded after the call ended, and the system destroys it - the mute goes off.

But, if you keep your process alive, its important that you keep a reference to your AlarmManager. A bug I found is, if you call `setStreamMute(..., true)` and then lose your reference, no matter how many times you call `setStreamMute(..., false)` it never unmutes.

So just hold a static reference to the AudioManager.

Comment: Your code references AlarmManager, which does not have a `setStreamMute` method.  You meant AudioManager, right?